# Match date in a varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I have a SQL Server table that stores Time as follows (in a `varchar` column):

```
08 SEP 2015 09:15:16
08 SEP 2015 09:15:22
08 SEP 2015 09:15:22
08 SEP 2015 09:15:22
08 SEP 2015 09:15:26
08 SEP 2015 09:15:27
08 SEP 2015 09:15:31
```

I want to write a query that can give me all entries that are in a particular month and year. Like 'JAN 2016' and so on.

I am using SQL Server.

Comment: i suggest you to cast this values to datetime and then filter them as you want

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all! And for time - use `TIME` - not `varchar`!!

Comment: I am working on a company database and this is how they do it. I can't change the database. If it were my choice i would use datetime as well.

Comment: @Farrokh how do i convert the values to datetime.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql#date-and-time-styles

Comment: Can there be a regex solution

Comment: You can't reliably convert `08 SEP 2915` to a date unless you also force that every user will use US English language and regional settings. Fight back and tell the company they designed the database wrong and should fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, I would recommend to change this data type to a date/timestamp field in order to avoid risk of data inconsistency and/or having part of your application crashing when trying to convert string (that do not respect the format of a date) to a date object.

Now **if and only if it is not feasible in short term**, you have two ways to proceed:

**1. data conversion:**

*The first one is to extract all the records from the table and convert them to date type before doing the comparison, 
however if there is at least one `varchar` that is not a well formed `date`, your query will fail.*

**2. work with string:**

Another way of doing is to query your DB directly using a `varchar` like described hereunder to avoid those conversion issues:

```
select * from table_A where date_column like '%JAN 2016%'
```

However query using `like` are **kind of slow** and should only be used as a temporary work-around, **in long term adapt your data model to ease 
your life and have a more stable/robust application**.

Last but not least, try to run some queries to check if there are not already some wrong data (format or strings that are not dates) inserted in your DB. You might face already some data inconsistency issues.

Answer (score 2):

If, you are not able to change the type of dates that you have then you will need to *cast* them with `format()` function to format the date(*MMM yyyy*)  available from *2012+*

```
SELECT 
       FORMAT(CAST(<column> AS DATE), 'MMM yyyy') as dates
FROM table t
```

You could also use the `datepart()` function to filter the dates

```
WHERE 
DATEPART(MONTH, dates) = 1 and DATEPART(year, dates) = 2015
```

In order to just the want to display the counts use `count()` function

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, dates) = 1 AND 
      DATEPART(year, dates) = 2015
```

Comment: I am on SQLServer-2008 and I am not sure 103 is the correct format a closer option is 9 or 13, but there is no AM/PM in the data

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar... use `datepart() ` function to filter the dates if you don't have any other options & yes there would be no need to use convert function.

Comment: I don't want to show the dates, I just want the count. How do I do this if I just want the counts.

Comment: @PiyushDivyanakar.. use count function `count(*)`